# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

I have problem with my code. (I've looked for some solution but i didn't found anything, so thats why I'm posting a topic)

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in XXXXXX on line 13
```

Line 13:

```
echo $view->;htmlError();
```

My code:

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/View.php';

echo DB_HOSTNAME; //output: hostname

$view = new View();

if ($htmlString = $view->tableThreads()) {
    echo $htmlString;
} else {
    echo $view->;htmlError();
}

echo $view->buttonPostThread();
?>
```

View.php

```
// we need the class db to make an object
require_once 'database.php';

//we'll also need the recaptcha helper later
require_once 'helpers/recaptcha.php';

class View{

    private $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    function tableThreads()
    {
        $content = "";

        if (($threads = $this->db->getThreads()) && mysql_num_rows($threads) > 0) {
             $content .= '<h1>Threads</h1>';
             $content .= '<table border="0" width="" id="posts_list">';
             $content .= '<tr>';
             $content .= '<th class="title">Title</td>';
             $content .= '<th>Date</td>';
             $content .= '<th>User</td>';
             $content .= '</tr>';

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($threads)) {
                $content .= '<tr class="thread">';
                $content .= '<td class="title">';
                $content .= '<a href="view_thread.php?permalink=';
                $content .= htmlspecialchars($row['permalink']) . '">'.$row['title'].'</a>';
                $content .= '</td>';
                $content .= '<td class="date">'.htmlspecialchars($row['date']).'</td>';
                $content .= '<td class="author">'.htmlspecialchars($row['author']).'</td>';
                $content .= '</tr>';
            }
            $content .= '</table>';
            return $content;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

private function composeTable($post, $firstPost, $numRows)
{
    $htmlTable = "";

    if ($firstPost)
        $htmlTable .= '<h1>'.htmlspecialchars($post['title']).'</h1>';

    $htmlTable .= '<table border="0" width="895">';
    $htmlTable .= ' <tr>';
    $htmlTable .= '     <th>Message</th>';
    $htmlTable .= '     <th>Date</th>';
    $htmlTable .= '     <th>Author</th>';
    $htmlTable .= ' </tr>';
    $htmlTable .= ' <tr>';
    $htmlTable .= '     <td class="title">'.htmlspecialchars($post['content']).'</td>';
    $htmlTable .= '     <td class="date">'.htmlspecialchars($post['date']).'</td>';
    $htmlTable .= '     <td class="author">'.htmlspecialchars($post['author']).'</td>';
    $htmlTable .= ' </tr>';
    $htmlTable .= '</table>';
    if ($firstPost && $numRows &gt; 1)
        $htmlTable .= '<h1>Responses</h1>';

    return $htmlTable;
}

function tableThreadContent($permalink)
{
    $content = "";

    if ($posts = $this->db->getContentThread($permalink)) {
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($posts);
        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts))
                $content .= $this->composeTable($row,
                    is_null($row['permalink_parent']),
                    $num_rows);
        }
        return $content;
    } else {
        return false;  //database error
    }
}

[/html]

<p>The second method goes around all the posts in a thread and composes the HTML with the first one (composeTable). </p>

<p>The method composeTable is private because we'll only call it from the tableThreadContent method in the same class and its functionality is only useful inside this class. In the future if we want to make a class that extends this one and uses that method all we need to do is change private for protected.</p>

<p>Now let's think about what happens if we don't have a single thread. Apart from being very sad it could be a problem if we don't show a warning message. This is a very simple method to do that:</p>

function htmlError($from_view_thread = false)
{
    if ($from_view_thread) {
        //From view_thread.php
        $html = '<p class="error">There is no thread with this title. Sorry! ';
        $html .= 'You can go back to <a href="index.php">the main page</a>.</p>';
    }else{
        // From index.php
        $html = '<p class="error">There aren\'t any threads. Sorry! </p>';
    }
    return $html;
}

function buttonPostThread()
{
    return '<div class="newThread">'
          .'<a href="post_message.php">Create a new thread</a>'
          .'</div>';
}
```

Comment: If the error says "*Unexpected ';' on line 13*", you need to look at all semicolons in line 13 one by one and ask yourself "Does this semicolon belong here?" A [good IDE with syntax highlighting](http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-ide-2014-survey-results/) helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct the line:

```
echo $view->;htmlError();
```

To:

```
echo $view->htmlError();
```

For rest, please check your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to substitute the line 13 for:

```
echo $view->html Error();
```

because you have an extra ";"

Answer (score 0):

in PHP 5.5 and above

```
$this->middlewares[$k] = Instance::ensure($middleware, Middleware::class);
```

and in PHP 5.5 below

```
$this->middlewares[$k] = Instance::ensure($middleware, 'Middleware');
```

PHP 5.4 not Support Class::class